# Basis for $V$ from basis for subspace $U$ and quotient space $V/U$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, quotient-spaces

As the title says, I’m trying to show that if $E$ is a basis for subspace $U$ and $f+U, f\in F$ is a basis for the quotient space $V/U$, then the union $E\cup F$ is a basis for $V$.

I need to show independence and spanning. For spanning, take $v\in V$. Consider $v+U$. As $f+U, f\in F$ is a basis for $V/U$, we can write $v+U=a_1(f_1 + U) + \dots + a_r(f_r + U)$ for some scalars $a_i$.

How do I proceed?

Edit: I have already proved linear indpendence.

Comment: Ok, do you know how to simplify this equality? Do you know how addition and scalar multiplication are defined in the quotient?

Comment: @Mark Yes, I know the definitions of the operations. We can write $v+U=(a_1f_1+\dots + a_rf_r) + U$.

Comment: Right, and so we have $v-(a_1f_1+...+a_rf_r)\in U$. And you know that $E$ is a basis of $U$. Can you finish from here?

Comment: @Mark Oh I see, then their difference is in $U$! And it follows. Thanks for the prompt